# How to get diagonal co-ordinates for Google map view in android

Tags: android, google-maps

In my android app, I am displaying a Google map for diff locations for which I have their lat & long. But now I am required to get diagonal co-ordinates i.e.  ne_lat,ne_long,sw_lat and sw_long and display the view on map based on this. 
How to achieve this ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
GoogleMap map = // get reference to google map instance

if(map != null){
       LatLngBounds visibleBounds = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

       Log.i("SW", visibleBounds.southwest.toString());
       Log.i("NE", visibleBounds.northeast.toString());
}
```

Hope that helps